# Can't change drive permission

Tags: permissions, steam, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu I installed steam in this and I want to install DotA2 but I don't want to install in my 20 GB partition instead I want to install in my remaining 480 GB partition.

The problem is here :
Owner permission : read and write
Group permission : none
Other : None

I want Other to be "Read and write"

Even if I change from permission it changes to none in 10 seconds.

EDIT:

I Solved it by installing ubuntu on main disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Reinstalled Ubuntu on main Disk

ie. the main 500 GB hdd rather than 20 gb partition

Then to change permission i used gksu nautilus

Answer (score 0):

To add read and write permissions to the `Other` group, assuming that you are the `Owner` and/or belong to the `Group` group and that the partition's mount point is `/media/<username>/<partition_mount_point>`:

```
chmod o+rw /media/<username>/<partition_mount_point>
```

If you are not the `Owner` and you don't belong to the `Group` group, you'll need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo chmod o+rw /media/<username>/<partition_mount_point>
```

To add read and write permissions to yourself, assuming that you belong to the `Group` group:

```
chmod g+rw /media/<username>/<partition_mount_point>
```

Comment: can u use team viewer to view ?
ID: 115 122 091 pass :2674

Comment: No i can't. You'll need to run the above command in a `Terminal`, you can open a `Terminal` by hitting Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard. `<username>` is your username in `Ubuntu` and the `<partition_mount_point>` can be found by accessing the partition in `Files` and looking at the top bar's name

Comment: i did still i dont have permission to write :(

Comment: I edited the question to make everything clearer

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is non-standard.  There exists a [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/) that describes where every and all software must reside.

That being said, this is *your Personal* Computer, so you can do whatever you want.  ;-)

I would install according to the standard and then copy the application/data to it's own home directory.

```
sudo cp --preserve --recursive /opt/WhatEver /home/WhatEver
```

This is perfect if your `/` is on the 20GB SSD and the `/home` is on a HDD somewhere (which is how I run).  Then I would delete the original:

```
sudo rm --recursive --force /opt/WhatEver
```

and now create a symbolic link in the old directory and point it to the new one:

```
cd /opt
sudo ln --symbolic /home/WhatEver
```

Where `Whatever` is whatever the name is of the application/directory it's installing to.

;-)